# Facebook API limit to get the profile picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a mobile application which has option to post comments about a post.

The only way to be able to use this feature is if you identify yourself using facebook.

So here comes the question:

When somebody clicks to read the comments i use the facebook profile picture of the user who post a comment which means that if there are 100+ comments bellow a post i have to make 100+ facebook request:

"https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=" + "square";

Is this OK?

Is it possible facebook to block the IP address of the user that makes these requests?

Comment: Should i cache the profile pictures of the users or always make a request to facebook to get them?

Comment: The results of implementing additional caching on your end will likely pale in comparison to the effort - just not worth it. For the actual CDN URLs that the above URLs redirect to, Facebook has done what’s necessary in regard to caching already.